# Runs monit as non-root user

Tags: ubuntu, non-root-user, monit

I'm using [Monit](https://github.com/arnaudsj/monit) to monitor my nodejs process. Right now `monit` itself runs as the root user which may lead to security holes. How could I run `monit` via the 'monit' user?

I installed `monit` by using `apt-get install monit`. So at the moment, it starts at system start up.

I just want accomplish the rule that all services that listen on port must be run as a non-root user.

I've found [a vulnerability](http://www.gentoo.org/security/en/glsa/glsa-200404-16.xml) that makes me prefer not to run monit as root. Or at least disable access via http interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not convinced that it's an issue having `monit` run as root so long as access to it is limited correctly. Looking at the config file, `/etc/monit/monitrc` I noticed this section to the file:

```
## Monit has an embedded web server which can be used to view status of 
## services monitored and manage services from a web interface. See the
## Monit Wiki if you want to enable SSL for the web server. 
#
# set httpd port 2812 and
#    use address localhost  # only accept connection from localhost
#    allow localhost        # allow localhost to connect to the server and
#    allow admin:monit      # require user 'admin' with password 'monit'
#    allow @monit           # allow users of group 'monit' to connect (rw)
#    allow @users readonly  # allow users of group 'users' to connect readonly
#
```

You could simply only allow access to the HTTP server by only allowing access to it via localhost. This will completely wall `monit` off so that only access to it is allowed locally. You can then setup SSH tunnels if you need to access it later on using `ssh -R 8080:monitserver:80 monitserver` for example.